# AttributeError where 'object has no attribute' - Python

Tags: python

Having some difficulty getting this code to run. I am supposed to find the total of the incomes, however I can't get the the incomes to print whatsoever.

```
class worker:

    def __init__(self, name, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex


class salaryWorker(worker):
    def __init__(self, name, sex, salary):
        worker.__init__(self, name, sex)
        self.salary = salary
        self.salaryIncome = (salary + (salary * .1))


    def annualIncome(self):
        print(self.salaryIncome)


class hourlyWorker(worker):
    def __init__(self, name, sex, hourlyRate, hourPerWeek):
        worker.__init__(self, name, sex)
        self.hourlyRate = hourlyRate
        self.hourPerWeek = hourPerWeek
        self.hourlyIncome = 52 * hourlyRate * hourPerWeek

    def annualIncome(self):
        print(self.hourlyIncome)




list1 = [salaryWorker('Andy','male', 40000), salaryWorker('Betty', 'female', 50000),
         hourlyWorker('Cindy', 'female', 21, 30), hourlyWorker('Dave', 'male', 19, 40)]




total = 0
list1.annualIncome()
print(total)
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'annualIncome'

Comment: Are you trying to call `annualIncome` on each *element in the list*?

Comment: This code produces no such error, nor does it produce any output.

Comment: `annualIncome()` is a method of workers, not the list.

Comment: You want `total = sum(w.annualIncome() for w in list1)`

Comment: @Barmar that is, if ``annualIncome`` would return anything ...

Comment: `list1 = [ ... ]` list1 is obviously a list.  Why do you expect it to have an `annualIncome` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you calling `annualIncome()` from a list? `annualIncome()` is a part of `salaryWorker`s and `hourlyWorker`s, not lists. Secondly, `annualIncome()` doesn't actually give you the value in a way you can use in code. Currently, it's printing to the console where the user can see it, but not the rest of the code. What you want to do is `return` `self.salaryIncome` and `self.hourlyIncome`. Then, what you want to do is loop through each worker in the list and then find the `annualIncome()` of each worker. Then add each to the total.

I'm going to give you the correct code below, but I encourage you to not copy-paste it, but instead read what I've written above and try and fix it yourself.

```
class worker:
    def __init__(self, name, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex


class salaryWorker(worker):
    def __init__(self, name, sex, salary):
        worker.__init__(self, name, sex)
        self.salary = salary
        self.salaryIncome = (salary + (salary * .1))

    def annualIncome(self):
        return self.salaryIncome


class hourlyWorker(worker):
    def __init__(self, name, sex, hourlyRate, hourPerWeek):
        worker.__init__(self, name, sex)
        self.hourlyRate = hourlyRate
        self.hourPerWeek = hourPerWeek
        self.hourlyIncome = 52 * hourlyRate * hourPerWeek

    def annualIncome(self):
        return self.hourlyIncome


list1 = [salaryWorker('Andy','male', 40000), salaryWorker('Betty', 'female', 50000),
         hourlyWorker('Cindy', 'female', 21, 30), hourlyWorker('Dave', 'male', 19, 40)]

total = 0
for w in list1:
    total += w.annualIncome()
print(total)
```

P.S. This is not essential to making the code work, but please use proper python formatting. `CapitalizeClassNames`, `snake_case_variable_names`, and use more descriptive variables than `list1`

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex


class SalaryWorker(Worker):
    def __init__(self, name, sex, salary):
        Worker.__init__(self, name, sex)
        self.salary = salary
        self.salary_income = (salary + (salary * .1))

    def annual_income(self):
        return self.salary_income


class hourlyWorker(Worker):
    def __init__(self, name, sex, hourly_rate, hours_per_week):
        Worker.__init__(self, name, sex)
        self.hourly_rate = hourly_rate
        self.hours_per_week = hours_per_week
        self.hourly_income = 52 * hourly_rate * hours_per_week

    def annual_income(self):
        return self.hourly_income


workers = [SalaryWorker('Andy','male', 40000), SalaryWorker('Betty', 'female', 50000),
         hourlyWorker('Cindy', 'female', 21, 30), hourlyWorker('Dave', 'male', 19, 40)]

total = 0
for worker in workers:
    total += worker.annualIncome()
print(total)
```